# Javascript hoisting issue-first and second debug return different value

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i tried to run a script for developing an add-on. Somehow, the first run will return undefined and only the second run will obtain the result i desire. I searched through and realised it might be something related with hoisting. Any ideas on this? Thanks.

```
var array1=[];
var array2=[];
var arrayPDS=[];
var arrayPD=[];
var suggPD;
function handleClick(state) {   
var suggPD = Request({   
  url: "http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=" + primarydomain,
  overrideMimeType: "application/xml; charset=latin1",
    onComplete: suggPDparse,
}).get();

function suggPDparse(response) {
     var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
     var parser = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/domparser;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMParser);
       var xml = parser.parseFromString(response.text, "application/xml");  

     var pds;
     var pd = xml.getElementsByTagName("suggestion");

     for (i=1;i<pd.length;i++){
              pds = pd[i].getAttribute("data");
           array1.push(pds);
           arrayPDS = array1[0];
     }

     function loadXMLDoc(filename, callback){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

         req.open("GET",filename,true);
         req.onreadystatechange = function(){
             if(req.readyState === 4){
                 callback(req.responseXML);
             }
         }
         req.send();
     }

     loadXMLDoc(self.data.url("pd.xml"), function(xmlDoc){
        if (xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName=="parsererror"){
              console.log(xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
              return(null);
           }

         var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Row");

        for (i=0; i<x.length; i++){
           var a=x[i];

             getV=(a.getElementsByTagName("Field_0")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
              array2.push(getV);            
        }
        arrayPD = array2;
     });
  }         
  console.log("arrayPD: " + arrayPD);
  console.log("arrayPDS: " + arrayPDS);
}
```

The result for first click will return:
arrayPD:
arrayPDS:

The result for second click will return:
arrayPD:abcd
arrayPDS:abcd

Comment: it is not because of hoisting the problem is you are using ajax which is asynchronous in nature... so you need to move the console logging statement to the `loadXMLDoc` method

Comment: yes, i know that i can move the console to loadXMLDoc but the problem is that i wan to make the arrayPDS and arrayPD be accessed globally as i want to use the 2 arrays in the next part.  ** This is only part of my coding** Do you know which part that i did it wrongly?

Comment: As the first comment says - it's just because the first time you click, the request to the remote server hasn't finished yet so the code hasn't run yet. If you move your console.log calls inside the callback for loadXMLDoc the data will be there.